# vba code for button click ms excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Data Entry]

[image: Chart after button execution]

As shown in the first picture, when i enter data in saturday column,simultaneously the Hours column  cell colour should change to green if the data is greater than 1. Then when i click saturday button as shown in picture 2, chart should show like this. its ok

Now when i enter data in sunday column as (pic 1), the hour column should refresh and the cell colour should come according to sunday column data.How can i do this??.Corresponding pic 2 also should refresh when i click sundy button in pic 2.

Thanks.Hope for a positive response

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim myseries As Series

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each myseries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection

        If myseries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie
        s = Split(myseries.Formula, ",")(2)
        vntValues = myseries.Values

        For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
            myseries.Points(i).Interior.Color = range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color


        Next i
SkipNotPie:
    Next myseries
Next cht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had searched for it, you would have found the next event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

From [ms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel) site.

Adjust this sample to your desires. So replace the MsgBox-line with code to change the background color of the button.